# In this question on random variables with normal distribution, how did they get $E[X-Y] = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X-Y] = 2.$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

> Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables with $X$ having a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$, $Y$ having the standard normal distribution.
>
> $\mathrm{(a)}$ Find the density of $Z=\min\{X,Y\}$.
>
> $\mathrm{(b)}$ For each $t\in\mathbb R$ compute $\mathbb P(\max\{X,Y\} - \min\{X,Y\}>t)$.

Wouldn't $E(X-Y) = \mu-1?$ I see how $\operatorname{Var}(X-Y) = 1+(-1)^2 = 2,$ since these are independent variables. However I do not understand how they got $E(X-Y) = \mu.$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: It is $\mathbb E(X-Y)=\mu-0$, since the standard normal distribution has an expected value of $0$ And the variance is just $Var(X-Y)=\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2=1+1=2$

Comment: @AnotherUser would you kindly direct me on how to be able to find symbols easily, including how to put ranges on on integrals etc? I'm having a hard time finding these hence why I took a picture

Comment: $E(Y)=0.$ $E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y).$

Comment: @callculus42 the example states that the mean of X-Y is μ which is why I'm confused

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how'd you get E(Y) = 0 ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah. I've made an edit. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ooo right it is just a normal distribution... thank you!

Comment: What do ou think the expectation is for the standard normal distribution? The standard normal distribution is symmetric around $0,$ so the expected value can only be $0.$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews for some reason I had thought the mean of normal distribution was 1 but ofc it's not.

Comment: As it currently stands, the question about $X-Y$ has nothing to do with the problem statement which concerns $\min\{X,Y\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin it has to do with B because P(max{X,Y}−min{X,Y}>t) .= P(|X-Y|>t)

Comment: As you're getting used to this site, it's best to directly ask the question you would like assistance with, without information that's extraneous to that specific question. Either the problem statement is extraneous to your question about $X-Y$, or you actually want to know something about the expressions in the problem statement that you haven't asked; it will help us if you further edit the question to clarify which one of these is the case.

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin ... I'm still trying to best navigate this site... Also part of the example got cut off due to editing... I'm going to try to post the full answer to this question later on today...

Answer (score 1):

A) $$F_z(z) = P(Z\leq z) = 1 - P(\min(X,Y)\gt z),$$ for a fixed real number "z".
$$
1 - P(\min(X,Y)\gt z) = 1-P(X\gt z)P(Y\gt z) \\= 1-(1-\Phi(z-\mu))(1-\Phi(z))
$$
Therefore, $f_z(z) = (1-\Phi(z-\mu))\Phi'(z) + \Phi'(z-\mu)(1-\Phi(z))$.

B)For $t\gt 0$, $$P(\max(x,y)-\min(x,y)\gt z) = P(|X-Y|\gt z) \\= P(X-Y\gt z) + P(X-Y\lt -z).$$ Since $E(X-Y) = \mu$, and $Var(X-Y) = (-1)^2 + (1)^2 = 2$, then $P(X-Y\gt z) + P(X-Y\lt -z) = \Phi((-z-\mu)/\sqrt{2})+1-\Phi((z-\mu)/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've partly edited the answer to demonstrate how to format it better, can you look at what I've done and complete the formatting for the rest of the answer?

Comment: Yes thank you... I'm trying to learn the syntax. Been re-editing but then I keep finding more errors I've made. Right now it is not letting do anymore edits but let me try again...

Comment: As a a general rule, you only need one pair of dollar or double-dollar signs wrapping a math expression. Try e.g. "Therefore, `$$f_z(z) = (1-\Phi(z-\mu))*\Phi'(z)) + \Phi'(z-\mu))*(1-\Phi(z))$$`", which renders as
$$f_z(z) = (1-\Phi(z-\mu))*\Phi'(z)) + \Phi'(z-\mu))*(1-\Phi(z))$$

Comment: @user170231 thank you for the advise. That is very helpful. I will try to use that piece of information. For some reason the Greek letters only come through some of the times and I don't understand. I'll write the same thing at times and \mu and \Phi only come through sometimes....

Comment: It's probably better to look at the preview. You only need dollars around the whole equation.